# Create a voice channel only to view but not to join

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a statistics bot. If the channel is not yet created, it should be created automatically under a certain category.
However, I want to set the permission so that nobody can connect,  talk, create a video, or use the activity.

How can I make it so that everyone can see this channel, but no one can use it? These channels are usually marked with a lock.

I tried it with `speak = False`, but i got this error:

`TypeError: create_voice_channel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'speak'`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    
    activity = discord.Game(name="Sudoku", type=1)
    
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

    guilds = bot.guilds
    for guild in guilds:
        Member = len([m for m in guild.members if not m.bot])
        
        channel = get(guild.channels, name=f"Count: {Member}")
        if not channel:
            cat = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=<id>)
            Member_count_channels.append(await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Count: {Member}', category=cat, speak = False))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through discord overwrites:

```
perms = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
perms.connect = False
await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
```

The code gets the channel's existing permissions, sets the connect permission to false and then applies to the default role (everyone).

Comment: That does not work for me. Do I need to copy that after `Member_count_channels.append(await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Count: {Member}', category=cat, speak = False))` ?

Comment: As well as `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'overwrites_for'`

Comment: Just a hint, but I suggest you watching some python tutorials

Comment: @Test you need to put this after you assign/make  the channel. Also considering this is on the bot's on ready, remove the `ctx.` from the example. As Kejax stated, read up on python to understand how to do it better.